# Need pymongo data frame output as multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pymongo

this is my JSON input in MongoDB datasource.

```html
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("61b84ae8e831076431a67f9e"), 
    "nameId" : "A123R3", 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0), 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-12-14T07:42:31.764+0000"), 
    "data" : [
        {
            "sources" : [], 
            "_id" : ObjectId("61b84ae7abea48f85c97e37e"), 
            "inputImage" : "URL1", 
            "outputImage" : "URL2", 
            "timeTracks" : {
                "main" : {
                    "total" : 2.993, 
                    "actualTotal" : 2.993
                }
             },
            "source" : "ui"
        }, 
        {
            "sources" : [], 
            "_id" : ObjectId("61b84ae8c7dc60f88356bf97"), 
            "inputImage" : "URL3", 
            "outputImage" : "URL4", 
            "timeTracks" : {
                "main" : {
                    "total" : 3.283, 
                    "actualTotal" : 3.28
                }
             },     
                  "source" : "ui"
        }, 
        
    ], 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-12-14T07:42:32.082+0000")
}
```

I have above json as my input and
I Need an output data frame in python like below, thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Can you convert your json record into python dict please else we can't convert `ObjectId` and `ISODate`.

Comment: @Corralien don't know for convert my JSON into python dict.
ignore that Objectid .

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion - in your mongo `"$project"` query, **add** `"_id": 0` and convert ISO date to string format using `"$dateToString"`. After that you can go ahead as follow.

```
 data = { 
    "nameId" : "A123R3", 
    "createdAt" :"2021-12-14",
    "data" : [
        {
            "sources" : [], 
            "inputImage" : "URL1", 
            "outputImage" : "URL2", 
            "timeTracks" : {
                "main" : {
                    "total" : 2.993, 
                    "actualTotal" : 2.993
                }
             },
            "source" : "ui"
        }, 
        {
            "sources" : [], 
            "inputImage" : "URL3", 
            "outputImage" : "URL4", 
            "timeTracks" : {
                "main" : {
                    "total" : 3.283, 
                    "actualTotal" : 3.28
                }
             },     
                  "source" : "ui"
        }, 
        
    ], 
    "updatedAt" : "2021-12-14"
}
import pandas as pd
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=['data'], meta=['nameId','createdAt','updatedAt'], errors='ignore')

      sources inputImage outputImage source  timeTracks.main.total  timeTracks.main.actualTotal  nameId   createdAt   updatedAt
0      []       URL1        URL2     ui                  2.993                        2.993  A123R3  2021-12-14  2021-12-14
1      []       URL3        URL4     ui                  3.283                        3.280  A123R3  2021-12-14  2021-12-14
```